# Does http establish connection for request and response

Tags: http, communication, request-response

I have been reading contradicting statements about HTTP from various sources.
These are the three contradicting statements that I came across.

"HTTP is a connection-less protocol that does not establish connection to send request or receive response."

"Http is a connectionless protocol because the browser initiates the HTTP request and after the request is sent the client disconnects from server and waits for the response"

"Http is a connectionless protocol because the browser initiates the HTTP request and after the response is received the client disconnects from server and waits for the response"

As you can see the first statment says that it never establishes a connection. The second says it disconnects after a request. The third statement says it disconnects after response. So which one is true?

Comment: Oh.. depends on the definition of **"connectionless"**. If it was replaced with **"stateless"**, would the nature be more clear? "Connectionless" if often used, but *a* physical TCP connection must be established; it is just that there is no "full-duplex connection" established at the HTTP-protocol: there is a request, and then a response, and then the HTTP 'connection' is over. Compare HTTP ("connectionless") to WebSocket.

Comment: Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33477400/2864740